# Responsive image doesn't resize after orientation change

Tags: html, ios, css

Does someone know why these images do not rescale after orientation change (on mobile Safari)? What am I doing wrong?

```
<img src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/tv8ujyaospdbp3w/cnc-milling.jpg?dl=1" sizes="100vw" srcset="https://www.dropbox.com/s/1x5ci017vezp3r6/cnc-milling-270.jpg?dl=1 270w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lcq54tji9jsp5y/cnc-milling-520.jpg?dl=1 520w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/xjovbdbi4s53ztw/cnc-milling-810.jpg?dl=1 810w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/fy78j4xeq0apx4l/cnc-milling-1080.jpg?dl=1 1080w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4frh0e4l606s0b/cnc-milling-1350.jpg?dl=1 1350w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/cj79u4y6cp0fqx7/cnc-milling-1620.jpg?dl=1 1620w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/2eyi48ks1g5x9nn/cnc-milling-1890.jpg?dl=1 1890w, https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uynetkiyr5ypq3/cnc-milling-2160.jpg?dl=1 2160w"  alt="test">
```

https://codepen.io/pad/pen/gReLOg